# Can Windows 7 Ultimate be installed over windows 7 starter?

Tags: windows-7, installation

Can Windows 7 Ultimate be installed over windows 7 starter?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx) is the technet article on Windows 7 upgrade paths.